# Как сделать, чтоб приложение на python работало без python на другом компьютере

Tags: python

Как сделать, чтоб приложение на python работало без python на другом компьютере?

Comment: Можно в интернете запустить, можно расширение для хрома поставить

Comment: еще упаковать в exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упаковать в один файл cx_Freeze, py2exe или аналоги.